# What's the best way to set the color of the status bar to a gradient drawable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-drawable, android-statusbar

So right now I have a bunch of activities and fragments that have the following code in `onCreate` or `onViewCreated`:

```
val window = this.window
val background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(this.resources, R.drawable.background_color, null)
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, android.R.color.transparent)
window.setBackgroundDrawable(background)
```

This sets the status bar to a drawable with a gradient color. The problem with this is that I don't like having to copy and paste this code into every activity and fragment I have. Not only that, this doesn't work for my `SplashActivity` which is the first activity that gets launched when the user runs the app for the first time. So what's the best way to set the status bar color to a custom gradient color and a way that also works for the first activity that gets launched?

Comment: Why not having a base Activity/Fragment (e.g GradientActivity/GradientFragment), implement the gradient code there and have your Activities/Fragments extend it?

Comment: You don't have to copy-paste the code. Put this in an extension function, and then it's one simple function call in each Activity, of which there should be very few in an app.

Answer (score -1):

> this is an full object for change status bar

```
object StatusBarUtil {
    
val DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA = 112
    private val FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID = R.id.statusbarutil_fake_status_bar_view
    private val FAKE_TRANSLUCENT_VIEW_ID = R.id.statusbarutil_translucent_view
    private val TAG_KEY_HAVE_SET_OFFSET = -123
    
    @JvmOverloads
    fun setColor(
        activity: Activity, @ColorInt color: Int, @IntRange(
            from = 0,
            to = 255
        ) statusBarAlpha: Int = DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity.window.statusBarColor = calculateStatusColor(color, statusBarAlpha)
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            val decorView = activity.window.decorView as ViewGroup
            val fakeStatusBarView = decorView.findViewById<View>(FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID)
            if (fakeStatusBarView != null) {
                if (fakeStatusBarView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                    fakeStatusBarView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                fakeStatusBarView.setBackgroundColor(calculateStatusColor(color, statusBarAlpha))
            } else {
                decorView.addView(createStatusBarView(activity, color, statusBarAlpha))
            }
            setRootView(activity)
        }
    }
    
    @JvmOverloads
    fun setColorForSwipeBack(
        activity: Activity, @ColorInt color: Int,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int = DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    
            val contentView = activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
            val rootView = contentView.getChildAt(0)
            val statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(activity)
            if (rootView != null && rootView is CoordinatorLayout) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    rootView.fitsSystemWindows = false
                    contentView.setBackgroundColor(calculateStatusColor(color, statusBarAlpha))
                    val isNeedRequestLayout = contentView.paddingTop < statusBarHeight
                    if (isNeedRequestLayout) {
                        contentView.setPadding(0, statusBarHeight, 0, 0)
                        rootView.post { rootView.requestLayout() }
                    }
                } else {
                    rootView.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(
                        calculateStatusColor(
                            color,
                            statusBarAlpha
                        )
                    )
                }
            } else {
                contentView.setPadding(0, statusBarHeight, 0, 0)
                contentView.setBackgroundColor(calculateStatusColor(color, statusBarAlpha))
            }
            setTransparentForWindow(activity)
        }
    }
    
    
    fun setColorNoTranslucent(activity: Activity, @ColorInt color: Int) {
        setColor(activity, color, 0)
    }
    
    @Deprecated("")
    fun setColorDiff(activity: Activity, @ColorInt color: Int) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        transparentStatusBar(activity)
        val contentView = activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
        val fakeStatusBarView = contentView.findViewById<View>(FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID)
        if (fakeStatusBarView != null) {
            if (fakeStatusBarView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                fakeStatusBarView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            fakeStatusBarView.setBackgroundColor(color)
        } else {
            contentView.addView(createStatusBarView(activity, color))
        }
        setRootView(activity)
    }
    
    
    @JvmOverloads
    fun setTranslucent(
        activity: Activity, @IntRange(
            from = 0,
            to = 255
        ) statusBarAlpha: Int = DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        setTransparent(activity)
        addTranslucentView(activity, statusBarAlpha)
    }
    
    fun setTranslucentForCoordinatorLayout(
        activity: Activity,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        transparentStatusBar(activity)
        addTranslucentView(activity, statusBarAlpha)
    }
    
    fun setTransparent(activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        transparentStatusBar(activity)
        setRootView(activity)
    }
    
    
    @Deprecated("")
    fun setTranslucentDiff(activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            setRootView(activity)
        }
    }
    
    fun setColorNoTranslucentForDrawerLayout(
        activity: Activity,
        drawerLayout: DrawerLayout,
        @ColorInt color: Int
    ) {
        setColorForDrawerLayout(activity, drawerLayout, color, 0)
    }
    
    @JvmOverloads
    fun setColorForDrawerLayout(
        activity: Activity, drawerLayout: DrawerLayout, @ColorInt color: Int,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int = DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity.window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        } else {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        }
        val contentLayout = drawerLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
        val fakeStatusBarView = contentLayout.findViewById<View>(FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID)
        if (fakeStatusBarView != null) {
            if (fakeStatusBarView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                fakeStatusBarView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            fakeStatusBarView.setBackgroundColor(color)
        } else {
            contentLayout.addView(createStatusBarView(activity, color), 0)
        }
        if (contentLayout !is LinearLayout && contentLayout.getChildAt(1) != null) {
            contentLayout.getChildAt(1)
                .setPadding(
                    contentLayout.paddingLeft,
                    getStatusBarHeight(activity) + contentLayout.paddingTop,
                    contentLayout.paddingRight,
                    contentLayout.paddingBottom
                )
        }
        setDrawerLayoutProperty(drawerLayout, contentLayout)
        addTranslucentView(activity, statusBarAlpha)
    }
    
    private fun setDrawerLayoutProperty(
        drawerLayout: DrawerLayout,
        drawerLayoutContentLayout: ViewGroup
    ) {
        val drawer = drawerLayout.getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup
        drawerLayout.fitsSystemWindows = false
        drawerLayoutContentLayout.fitsSystemWindows = false
        drawerLayoutContentLayout.clipToPadding = true
        drawer.fitsSystemWindows = false
    }
    
    @Deprecated("")
    fun setColorForDrawerLayoutDiff(
        activity: Activity,
        drawerLayout: DrawerLayout,
        @ColorInt color: Int
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            val contentLayout = drawerLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
            val fakeStatusBarView = contentLayout.findViewById<View>(FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID)
            if (fakeStatusBarView != null) {
                if (fakeStatusBarView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                    fakeStatusBarView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                fakeStatusBarView.setBackgroundColor(
                    calculateStatusColor(
                        color,
                        DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA
                    )
                )
            } else {
                contentLayout.addView(createStatusBarView(activity, color), 0)
            }
            if (contentLayout !is LinearLayout && contentLayout.getChildAt(1) != null) {
                contentLayout.getChildAt(1).setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(activity), 0, 0)
            }
            setDrawerLayoutProperty(drawerLayout, contentLayout)
        }
    }
    
    @JvmOverloads
    fun setTranslucentForDrawerLayout(
        activity: Activity, drawerLayout: DrawerLayout,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int = DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        setTransparentForDrawerLayout(activity, drawerLayout)
        addTranslucentView(activity, statusBarAlpha)
    }
    
    fun setTransparentForDrawerLayout(activity: Activity, drawerLayout: DrawerLayout) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity.window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        } else {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        }
    
        val contentLayout = drawerLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
        if (contentLayout !is LinearLayout && contentLayout.getChildAt(1) != null) {
            contentLayout.getChildAt(1).setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(activity), 0, 0)
        }
        setDrawerLayoutProperty(drawerLayout, contentLayout)
    }
    
    @Deprecated("")
    fun setTranslucentForDrawerLayoutDiff(activity: Activity, drawerLayout: DrawerLayout) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            val contentLayout = drawerLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
            contentLayout.fitsSystemWindows = true
            contentLayout.clipToPadding = true
            val vg = drawerLayout.getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup
            vg.fitsSystemWindows = false
            drawerLayout.fitsSystemWindows = false
        }
    }
    
    
    fun setTransparentForImageView(activity: Activity, needOffsetView: View) {
        setTranslucentForImageView(activity, 0, needOffsetView)
    }
    
    fun setTranslucentForImageView(activity: Activity, needOffsetView: View) {
        setTranslucentForImageView(activity, DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA, needOffsetView)
    }
    
    fun setTranslucentForImageView(
        activity: Activity, @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int,
        needOffsetView: View?
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return
        }
        setTransparentForWindow(activity)
        addTranslucentView(activity, statusBarAlpha)
        if (needOffsetView != null) {
            val haveSetOffset = needOffsetView.getTag(TAG_KEY_HAVE_SET_OFFSET)
            if (haveSetOffset != null && haveSetOffset as Boolean) {
                return
            }
            val layoutParams = needOffsetView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            layoutParams.setMargins(
                layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin + getStatusBarHeight(activity),
                layoutParams.rightMargin, layoutParams.bottomMargin
            )
            needOffsetView.setTag(TAG_KEY_HAVE_SET_OFFSET, true)
        }
    }
    
    fun setTranslucentForImageViewInFragment(activity: Activity, needOffsetView: View) {
        setTranslucentForImageViewInFragment(activity, DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_ALPHA, needOffsetView)
    }
    
    fun setTransparentForImageViewInFragment(activity: Activity, needOffsetView: View) {
        setTranslucentForImageViewInFragment(activity, 0, needOffsetView)
    }
    
    fun setTranslucentForImageViewInFragment(
        activity: Activity, @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int,
        needOffsetView: View
    ) {
        setTranslucentForImageView(activity, statusBarAlpha, needOffsetView)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            clearPreviousSetting(activity)
        }
    }
    
    fun hideFakeStatusBarView(activity: Activity) {
        val decorView = activity.window.decorView as ViewGroup
        val fakeStatusBarView = decorView.findViewById<View>(FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID)
        if (fakeStatusBarView != null) {
            fakeStatusBarView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        val fakeTranslucentView = decorView.findViewById<View>(FAKE_TRANSLUCENT_VIEW_ID)
        if (fakeTranslucentView != null) {
            fakeTranslucentView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun setLightMode(activity: Activity) {
        setMIUIStatusBarDarkIcon(activity, true)
        setMeizuStatusBarDarkIcon(activity, true)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
    }
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun setDarkMode(activity: Activity) {
        setMIUIStatusBarDarkIcon(activity, false)
        setMeizuStatusBarDarkIcon(activity, false)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
    }
    
    private fun setMIUIStatusBarDarkIcon(activity: Activity, darkIcon: Boolean) {
        val clazz = activity.window.javaClass
        try {
            val layoutParams = Class.forName("android.view.MiuiWindowManager\$LayoutParams")
            val field = layoutParams.getField("EXTRA_FLAG_STATUS_BAR_DARK_MODE")
            val darkModeFlag = field.getInt(layoutParams)
            val extraFlagField =
                clazz.getMethod(
                    "setExtraFlags",
                    Int::class.javaPrimitiveType,
                    Int::class.javaPrimitiveType
                )
            extraFlagField.invoke(activity.window, if (darkIcon) darkModeFlag else 0, darkModeFlag)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
    private fun setMeizuStatusBarDarkIcon(activity: Activity, darkIcon: Boolean) {
        try {
            val lp = activity.window.attributes
            val darkFlag =
                WindowManager.LayoutParams::class.java.getDeclaredField("MEIZU_FLAG_DARK_STATUS_BAR_ICON")
            val meizuFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams::class.java.getDeclaredField("meizuFlags")
            darkFlag.isAccessible = true
            meizuFlags.isAccessible = true
            val bit = darkFlag.getInt(null)
            var value = meizuFlags.getInt(lp)
            if (darkIcon) {
                value = value or bit
            } else {
                value = value and bit.inv()
            }
            meizuFlags.setInt(lp, value)
            activity.window.attributes = lp
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private fun clearPreviousSetting(activity: Activity) {
        val decorView = activity.window.decorView as ViewGroup
        val fakeStatusBarView = decorView.findViewById<View>(FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID)
        if (fakeStatusBarView != null) {
            decorView.removeView(fakeStatusBarView)
            val rootView =
                (activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
            rootView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    }
    
    private fun addTranslucentView(
        activity: Activity,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) statusBarAlpha: Int
    ) {
        val contentView = activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
        val fakeTranslucentView = contentView.findViewById<View>(FAKE_TRANSLUCENT_VIEW_ID)
        if (fakeTranslucentView != null) {
            if (fakeTranslucentView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                fakeTranslucentView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            fakeTranslucentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(statusBarAlpha, 0, 0, 0))
        } else {
            contentView.addView(createTranslucentStatusBarView(activity, statusBarAlpha))
        }
    }
    
    private fun createStatusBarView(
        activity: Activity,
        @ColorInt color: Int,
        alpha: Int = 0
    ): View {
        val statusBarView = View(activity)
        val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            getStatusBarHeight(activity)
        )
        statusBarView.layoutParams = params
        statusBarView.setBackgroundColor(calculateStatusColor(color, alpha))
        statusBarView.id = FAKE_STATUS_BAR_VIEW_ID
        return statusBarView
    }
    
    private fun setRootView(activity: Activity) {
        val parent = activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
        var i = 0
        val count = parent.childCount
        while (i < count) {
            val childView = parent.getChildAt(i)
            if (childView is ViewGroup) {
                childView.setFitsSystemWindows(true)
                childView.clipToPadding = true
            }
            i++
        }
    }
    
    private fun setTransparentForWindow(activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            activity.window
                .decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            activity.window
                .setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                )
        }
    }
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private fun transparentStatusBar(activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
            activity.window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        } else {
            activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        }
    }
    
    private fun createTranslucentStatusBarView(activity: Activity, alpha: Int): View {
        val statusBarView = View(activity)
        val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            getStatusBarHeight(activity)
        )
        statusBarView.layoutParams = params
        statusBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, 0))
        statusBarView.id = FAKE_TRANSLUCENT_VIEW_ID
        return statusBarView
    }
    
    private fun getStatusBarHeight(context: Context): Int {
        val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
        return context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
    }
    
    private fun calculateStatusColor(@ColorInt color: Int, alpha: Int): Int {
        if (alpha == 0) {
            return color
        }
        val a = 1 - alpha / 255f
        var red = color shr 16 and 0xff
        var green = color shr 8 and 0xff
        var blue = color and 0xff
        red = (red * a + 0.5).toInt()
        green = (green * a + 0.5).toInt()
        blue = (blue * a + 0.5).toInt()
        return 0xff shl 24 or (red shl 16) or (green shl 8) or blue
    }
}
```

> and use :

```
StatusBarUtil.setColor(
            requireActivity(),
            Color.parseColor(
               "this is background color Viewpager "
            ),
            20
        )
```

Comment: Where did you find this code? This looks like overkill compared to what I was originally doing.